Is there any way to get original string with backslash from klish?
when i input this command
create monitor send_string "for test: \x74\x65\x73\x74\x20\x66\x6f\x72\x20\x68\x65\x78\x20\x63\x6f\x6e\x76\x65\x72\x74"

while print the value of send_string is for test: x74x65x73x74x20x66x6fx72x20x68x65x78x20x63x6fx6ex76x65x72x74
is's lost a blackslash.
sure, i can input two backslash to get backslash,
create monitor send_string "for test: \\x74\\x65\\x73\\x74\\x20\\x66\\x6f\\x72\\x20\\x68\\x65\\x78\\x20\\x63\\x6f\\x6e\\x76\\x65\\x72\\x74"

but it's will very complex, especially for escape charaters.
so, how can i got original string for klish.
klish version is 2.1.4.
how to get the original string while input string contains backslash.
